# How do I share my running docker-container and volume with others over the network so that they can see the changes they make to the software live?

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-network

We have locally set up a docker-container in Docker Engine and I need my coworkers to be able to access it over the network instead of running their own containers and volumes.

Generally this seems possible to do in Docker but I am not sure it actually is.

So if it is possible, how do I let them access it / share it with them?

Please try to answer in simple terms as I'm very new to programming and networking in general.

Comment: Changed the tags

Comment: What are you trying to do; set up a running instance of your system so others can use it, publish the built images through a continuous-integration system; something else?  What have you already tried?